# Can't connect using TCP though UDP/ICMP works

Tags: tcpip, filter

My office changed IP addresses yesterday and since then we can't access any site hosted by mediatemple.net plus a couple of other sites. The office connection is ADSL (PPPoA). Both MT and my ISP support can't help.

Pinging and tracerouting both work. All TCP attempts time out: HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, POP3, SMTP, telnetting random ports. I can use ssh via a ubuntu netbook connected through 3G so can do testing from both ends. I have been running tcpdump on the Media Temple (dv) box.

Normal traceroute and ping both show packets in the tcpdump. I have found traceroute -T appears to work but the packets aren't actually making it to the other host. (When using that option from the netbook, the packets are visible)

The new office IP address is 14.x.x.x which was only allocated to APNIC 6 months ago so I thought it might be on a bogon filter somewhere. MT support has said there's no filtering of that kind in their network. The old IP was 203.x.x.x, which was changed from a 59.x.x.x: both of them worked and no settings were changed on our end. I use the same ISP at home (203.x.x.x IP) with no problems.

Any other ideas?

Edit: I got a new IP address from my ISP which allowed it to work. It is not clear whether it is a problem in my ISP network or some sort of bogon filtering in Media Temple.

Comment: NAT protection by your ISP? DId you change ISP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an old bogon filter in MT's upstream and this was rectified. There were other non-MT sites affected, and other users of the same ISP were affected: see http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1568752